# Print color code selected to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a quick source for color picking in a rails app and I've got myself lost in trying to change what happens on the "click"; what I want is that when someone selects the color rather then printing the color hex in html, it would bring in value of input. So far I've done;

```
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').colorPicker(
        {
          click:function(c){
            $('input[value]').html(c);
          }
        });

    });</script>
```

and my input;

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :color, :value => '' %>
```

However I think I'm missing something in the way the click function works.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint inside your click handler to confirm it's actually been called when you think? Are you sure that the 'input[value]' selector is actually finding the field you are interested in?

Comment: Yes, what I've got in my javascript is; $(document).ready(function(){$('#color').colorPicker({color:['#16a085'],click:function(c){$('input[bin_color]').val(c);} .... bin_color being the ID of my input... the value i have set to empty on that input like this; <%= f.hidden_field :color %> on submission, it does grab the empty value, but I guess its not putting the selected color.

Comment: if I add <div id="output"></div> in my markup with $(document).ready(function(){$('#test').colorPicker({color: ['#16a085'], click: function(color){$('#output').html(color);}); }); it works perfectly fine printing the hex color to my div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
click: function (c) {
    $('input[color]').val(c);
}
```

Comment: nope that didn't do it. The original is;function(c){
       $('#output').html(c);
     }

Comment: then I have to put a <div id="output"></div> which prints the hex color, but in my situation I'm not trying to print it to the "output" div, but rather printing it in the input value so that rails saves it to the DB later.

Comment: If I understand your problem, this is the approach you need to take, you'll just need to figure out what the proper input selector is (I'm guessing it's `input[color]`) and then set the new value.

Answer (score 0):

I think so you need to use jscolor picker
http://jscolor.com/

Comment: I'm using this and have it all in but for some reason the value doesn't get printed, it does print if I do a <div id="output"></div> like on the website of this little source, but since java outputs it, it should be simple to tell it to put it in an input value that's hidden then into a div. http://www.syronex.com/software/jquery-color-picker

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed with the following;

changed from;

```
click: function (c) {
    $('input[color]').val(c);
}
```

to:

```
click: function (c) {
    $('#bin_color').val(c);
}
```

Thank you everyone